# why is RAND_MAX a macro in C++?

Tags: c++, random

Why is it not a `const`? I think this is not a clear C++ way. 
Perhaps there is a more C++ way to generate random numbers, is there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're looking for a "more C++-way", you could use `boost::random`.

*Anyway, `RAND_MAX` is a macro, because it comes from "legacy C" `rand()` function, where using preprocessor symbols for declaring constants was a de-facto standard.*

Answer (score 11):

`RAND_MAX` comes from the C standard library, where it is defined as a macro.

In C, macros are the way manifest constants are defined.  A `const` object isn't actually a constant in C (this means a `const` object cannot be used in constant expressions).

Answer (score 1):

It's a macro because it comes from C where it's been a macro for a long time.

1. Boost random would be one alternative.
2. TR1's random number generation classes would be another.
3. Unlike most of TR1, the PRNG classes are being completely revised for C++0x.

Comment: Thanks for TR1's random number generator